# What's the similarities and differences between Wigner transform and wavelet transform?

Tags: signal-analysis, wavelet, time-frequency

Wigner transform and continuous wavelet transform are both some kind of time-frequency representation of a signal.

What are the similarities and differences between them? Could you give some comparison between them? Let's restrict ourselves in 1D signal at the moment.

Comment: Wigner is not linear and involves a product that is roughly equivalent to the local autocorrelation, while a CWT is a linear operation.  Wigner has cross terms, CWT doesn't. Both are time frequency representations but the limits of integration are minus infinity to plus infinity for a Wigner, which implies that Wigner is noncausal while CWT is causal.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice tutorial: [Time-Frequency Toolbox For Use with MATLAB](http://tftb.nongnu.org/tutorial.pdf) tthat compares many transformations, notably continuous wavelet transform and Wigner and its avatars.

Basically, the CWT belongs to atomic linear representations (a decomposition onto wavelet atoms), while Wigner-Ville is an
energy distribution (to split the energy of signals over  time and frequency).

Since the tutorial comes with a toolbox and many examples, you can easily reproduce it on your signals.